# Notes on a different account (@gmail) and have icloud account. Unable to see the notes on icloud

Tags: icloud, gmail, notes.app

I have notes on my iphone. However the notes are in different account and not on the icloud account and I am unable to see the notes when I login to my icloud account. I have notes back up turned on. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I just found and fixed an issue that I had that may be related.  Somehow in settings on my iPhone I had Notes set with a default account of gmail.  I changed it to cloud and magically everything started synching again.  I have no idea how gmail became the default account as I don't use it for notes, but that worked...